# Merging CSV table rows according to the first column - sqlite

Tags: sql, excel, sqlite, csv

I am trying to migrate an excel database into sqlite, although I have no expertise in the latter.

My first step is to import a series of CSV files into an sql database (which I found fairly easy to do).
These tables have a common structure,i.e.

```
column1: timestamp
column2: temperature
column3: humidity
```

The second step is to merge rows from imported table, according to the value in the first column (timestamp). The data in the rows might overlap or have gaps e.g.:

```
timestamp,temperature,humidity
04/01/2016 09:00:00, 23.1, 45.5
04/01/2016 09:15:00, 23.3, 46
...
20/01/2016 15:15:00, 25, 40
```

with

```
timestamp,temperature,humidity
10/01/2016 09:00:00, 23.1, 45.5
10/01/2016 09:15:00, 23.3, 46
...
30/01/2016 15:15:00, 25, 40
```

How can I merge the two (or more) imported CSV, overwriting the common data and leaving blank (or NULL) values for the gaps into one master sql table?

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: i know how to import .csv files in to sqlite3, But am not sure bout the second scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My_Table** has following columns:

> time | temp | humidity

**example.csv** has the following data:

> 10/01/2016 09:15:00,23.1,45.5
>
> 10/01/2016 09:11:00,22.3,41.5
>
> 10/01/2016 09:15:00,23.1,42.5

Go to Sqlite3 terminal and run the following commands.

```
.separator ","
.import example.csv My_Table
```

Likewise you can import all of your csv files at last you can delete duplicate lines based on time.

```
delete from My_Table where rowid not in (select max(rowid) from My_Table group by time);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I assume that "time" will have to refer to an existing column in "My_Table"?